# Options for Feast production datasources?

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, amazon-redshift, feast

I'm looking into the FEAST feature store. I realize for production, datasources had to be either AWS redshift or Google Bigquery. (isn't this contradicts to the ideas of open source?) But I had my own small server (actually some AWS spot instance) I wanted to utilize. Is there a way to use Feast in production without actually using paying use AWS redshift or Google Bigquery?

Comment: The requirement to use certain other packages or libraries does not contradict open source ideas. Not having any restrictions would make it virtually impossible to write the software. in the first place. Nor does open source prohibit charging at least for a binary version. *Open Source* only means you can get, modify, and distribute the **source code**. So you can still download the FEAST source code and rewrite that section of code to use any data source you want. –

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [list of currently supported integrations](https://github.com/feast-dev/feast/tree/v0.19-branch#-functionality-and-roadmap). Red Shift and Big Query are just defaults if you use AWS/GCP provider. These defaults can be overwritten by simply modifying `feature_store.yaml`.

For instance:

```
registry: gs://anton-feast-tutorial/registry.db
project: fraud_tutorial
provider: gcp
online_store:
  type: redis
  connection_string: localhost:6379
```

The last there lines here would change the default GCP DataStore to your local Redis instance as an Online datastore.

Same approach works for data sources and offline store. This would add Postgres as your offline store:

```
...
offline_store:
    type: feast_postgres.PostgreSQLOfflineStore # MUST be this value
    host: localhost
    port: 5432              # Optional, default it 5432
    database: postgres
    db_schema: my_schema
    user: username
    password: password
```